# Contar número de vezes que letras repetem em um texto

Tags: python

Alguém pode me dar uma ideia de como escrever este algoritmo em Python em menos linhas ?(O algoritmo, conta a quantidade de determinada letra do alfabeto em uma string).

```
#INSERINDO TEXTO
string=input("Digite a string no qual quer ler quais letras do alfabetos elas possui:\t")

#DICIONARIO do alfabetos
alfabetos={'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0, 'e':0, 'f':0, 'g':0, 'h':0, 'i':0, 'j':0, 'k':0, 'l':0, 'm':0, 'n':0,
'o':0, 'p':0, 'q':0, 'r':0, 's':0, 't':0, 'u':0, 'v':0, 'w':0, 'x':0, 'y':0, 'z':0}

#PERCORRENDO A STRING (caractere por caractere)
for b in string:
    if ((b=='a') or (b=='A')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='b') or (b=='B')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='c') or (b=='C')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='d') or (b=='D')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='e') or (b=='E')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='f') or (b=='F')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='g') or (b=='G')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='g') or (b=='G')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='h') or (b=='H')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='i') or (b=='I')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='j') or (b=='J')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='k') or (b=='K')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='l') or (b=='L')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='m') or (b=='M')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='n') or (b=='N')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='o') or (b=='O')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='p') or (b=='P')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='q') or (b=='Q')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='r') or (b=='R')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='s') or (b=='S')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='t') or (b=='T')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='u') or (b=='U')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='v') or (b=='V')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='w') or (b=='W')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='x') or (b=='X')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='y') or (b=='Y')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1
    elif ((b=='z') or (b=='Z')):
        alfabetos[b]=alfabetos[b]+1

#VARIAVEL QUE CONTEM A CHAVES E CONTEUDO DO DICIONARIO
lista=list(alfabetos.items())

#PRINTANDO
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 4):

Sim, basta utilizar o [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), que já faz isso para você:

```
from collections import Counter

texto = 'Stack Overflow em Português'
counter = Counter(texto)

print(counter)
```

A saída é:

```
Counter({' ': 3, 't': 2, 'e': 2, 'r': 2, 'o': 2, 'u': 2, 'S': 1, 'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'k': 1, 'O': 1, 'v': 1, 'f': 1, 'l': 1, 'w': 1, 'm': 1, 'P': 1, 'g': 1, 'ê': 1, 's': 1})
```

Neste caso, ele considerará todos os caracteres presentes no texto, incluindo espaço e diferenciando letras acentuadas, `e` de `ê`, por exemplo, e letras minúsculas de maiúsculas, mas já dá para você começar a brincar.

Answer (score 3):

A forma mais direta e aconselhada é utilizar o que já existe, o `Counter`, tal como o @AndersonCarlosWoss já indicou.

No entanto pegando no seu algoritmo, consegue manualmente fazer o que quer sem muitas alterações. Antes começo que ele não funciona para letras maiusculas apesar de elas estarem contempladas nos `ifs` pois o dicionário não tem inicialmente as chaves maiusculas e dá erro quando tenta aceder a elas.

Se quer guardar ambas as versões (maiúscula / minúscula) como minúscula, então basta converter a frase toda para minúsculas com [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower) antes de percorrer:

```
for b in string.lower():
```

Também não precisa de criar as chaves inicialmente, pode criar à medida que elas vão surgindo na frase:

```
#DICIONARIO do alfabetos
alfabetos = {}

#PERCORRENDO A STRING (caractere por caractere)
for b in string.lower():
    alfabetos[b] = alfabetos[b] + 1 if b in alfabetos else 1
```

Agora em cada letra que passa, se não tiver ainda no `alfabetos` guarda com contagem `1` se já tiver guarda com a contagem que está mais `1`.

Daqui para interpretar apenas `a-z` basta mais um `if`:

```
#DICIONARIO do alfabetos
alfabetos = {}

#PERCORRENDO A STRING (caractere por caractere)
for letra in string.lower():
    if 'a' <= letra <= 'z':  # só se for letra
        alfabetos[letra] = alfabetos[letra] + 1 if letra in alfabetos else 1
```

Para a contagem dos números pode usar um `defaultdict(int)` que é uma subclasse de `dict` que lhe facilita, pois sempre que não tem valor vai considerar `0` e por isso evita o teste de existência:

```
from collections import defaultdict
#DICIONARIO do alfabetos
alfabetos = defaultdict(int)

#PERCORRENDO A STRING (caractere por caractere)
for letra in string.lower():
    if 'a' <= letra <= 'z':
        alfabetos[letra] += 1  # agora basta somar
```

Note que esta ultima alteração implicou adicionar mais um `import`

Answer (score -2):

```
for string in frase.lower():
for chave in alfabetos.keys():
    if string == chave:
        alfabetos[string] += 1
```